# .Net Core IMemoryCache keep calling Database if EF Query is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using IMemoryCache to store data in Cache... but it keeps sending sql calls to the SQL Server even though the execution does not run that code if the cache exists.

**My Lookup Service**

```
public class QueryLookups
    {
        private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;


        public QueryLookups(DbContexts.AppsecDbContext ctx, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            context = ctx;
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }

        public DbContexts.AppsecDbContext context
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetCourseAreas()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> result;

            // TryGet returns true if the cache entry was found
            if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue("CourseAreas", out result))
            {
                oak.Frameworks.Utils.Debug("No Cache found for 'CourseAreas' - Get from Database");

                result = context.CourseAreas.Where(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Area) == false).Select(s => s.Area).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s);

                _memoryCache.Set("CourseAreas", result, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)); // 1 hour cache
            }

            return result;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetAcademicYearIDs()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> result;

            // TryGet returns true if the cache entry was found
            if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue("AcademicYearIDs", out result))
            {
                oak.Frameworks.Utils.Debug("No Cache found for 'AcademicYearIDs' - Get from Database");
                IDbConnection db = context.Database.GetDbConnection();                
                result = db.Query<string>("SELECT DISTINCT AcademicYearID FROM dbo.ER_vBaseStudents;");                

                _memoryCache.Set("AcademicYearIDs", result, DateTime.Now.AddHours(5)); // 5 hours cache
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
```

My Test View.cshtml

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@LookupService.GetAcademicYearIDs().Select(g => new SelectListItem() { Text = g, Value = g })">
        <option value="">- All Years -</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@LookupService.GetCourseAreas().Select(g => new SelectListItem() { Text = g, Value = g })">
        <option value="">- All Areas -</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using MyProject
@inject MyProject.Queries.QueryLookups LookupService
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

TestController

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}
```

In theory, it shouldn't send the db commands to the SQL Server.  But according to the SQL Profiler, it is still sending even though it doesn't run the code to get the data from there.  It hits the cache and returning data from cache.  But it still runs SELECT xxxx to the DB too.

Strangely, in my lookup service, there are 2 methods.  GetAcademicYearIDs() method which uses Dapper is not doing the same.  It's doing it only for GetCourseAreas where I used EF syntax.

Could you please help me with this issue?  These database calls are very fast and less than 100 ms.  But I would like to know why it keeps doing and what I am doing wrong.

[image]

**Answer**
The Credit goes to the guru I met in London.Net User Group.  If you answer the question, I will mark your answer as the correct one.

The reason is because of the Lazy Loading feature of EFCore.  I am caching the entity directly without reading the data from the database.  Instead of that I added `.ToList()` to force the read and put the result back to the Cache.  And it works perfectly.

```
    result = context.CourseAreas.Where(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Area) == false).Select(s => s.Area).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s).ToList();

_memoryCache.Set("CourseAreas", result, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)); // 1 hour cache
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework Core  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"

Answer (score 0):

I think the call is to stop the cache going stale. You should be able to change the time rate at which it refreshes though [Microsoft IMemeoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory)